# Why does a switch statement perform equality testing differently from an if statement?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, switch-statement

Why does the `if` statement work in the example below while the [switch statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Ruby) does not.

- working:

  ```
  if ''.class == String
    puts "yep, that's a string"
  end
  ```
- not working:

  ```
  case ''.class
  when String
    puts "yep, that's a string, but this case is never triggered"
  end
  ```

In the trivial example above, the switch statement is overkill, but there are obviously situations where a switch statement would be DRYer than chained `elsif`s

Comment: Obviously, they are not equivalent. What makes you think they are?

Comment: My background in other languages. Point taken, question updated for accuracy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the case statement doesn't use the == operator, it uses the === operator (sometimes called the case equality operator).  What this does varies depending on what's on the left side of the operator.  So, if you were to transform case statement like this:

```
case "Some string"
when String
  puts "It's a string!"
else
  puts "It's not a string!"
end
```

Into an if statement, it would become this:

```
if String === "Some string"
  puts "It's a string!"
else
  puts "It's not a string!"
end
```

Note that Ruby does this *backwards* from how you'd expect, it does `String === "Some string"`.  This is because what you really want to do is call `Class#===` here, and not `String#===`.  What the === operator does for any object is really up to the class.  In the case of `Class#===`, it's roughly equivalent to calling `"Some string".is_a?(String)`.  But if you were to do `"a" === "b"`, the `String#===` method is roughly equivalent to `String#==`.

It *can* get confusing, but the operator's usage is largely idiomatic.  In other words, the "class object in a when statement" idiom means to test if the case object is of that class.  I've written an article on this that explains it a bit more, you can read it [here](http://ruby.about.com/od/control/a/The-Case-Equality-Operator.htm).

Comment: I know About.com gets [great traffic](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/about.com)...but if you'd only published that somewhere *readable*!

Comment: I'm sorry about that, but I'm working on it.  I'm now using a layout that doesn't have ads interrupting the content for new articles.  I don't know what I can do about older content though.

Comment: Great to hear. You wrote & published, and I thank you for that, no apology necessary.

Answer (score 11):

Actually, ruby's "case" makes the comparaison with ===

So your example is equivalent to :

```
if ''.class === String
   puts "yep, that's a string"
end
```

Comment: upvoted because you beat me to it by seconds! (and you're right :)

Comment: So since the triple equals is [a method defined on the left hand operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616912/ruby-triple-equal#5617086), and `String.===''` returns `true` while `String.=== String` returns `false`, the case does not run.

Comment: Actually, it would be `String === ''.class`.  It doesn't make a difference in this case, since both are Class instances, but it will in other cases.

Comment: @AboutRuby that's a fascinating implication that explains why your example works, even though `''.=== String` evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 5):

The quick and simple answer is that case uses `===` (3 equals) and not two.

```
$ irb                                                                 
if ''.class == String
  puts "yep, that's a string"   
end
```

> yep, that's a string

```
=> nil

if ''.class === String
  puts "yep, that's a string"
end
=> nil
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, `case` equality in Ruby works a bit differently than you might expect, so you can just do

```rb
case foo
when String # that is, when String === foo, more or less when foo.class == String
  do something
end
```

But generally, *you shouldn't*. If you're explicitly testing class names, then (usually) your OO design is flawed -- in most cases, you should try to use polymorphism instead.  In other words, instead of

```
if x.class == String
  x.process_string
else
  x.process_non_string
end
```

you should simply have `x.process`, and then define `process` differently for `String` and other classes. Cleaner, less code, doesn't force the caller to know the class of the called object.

Comment: `==` is commutative (unlike `===`), so reversing the order is not misleading. As to testing class names, the reason it's a smell is that objects know what class they are, and should be capable of their own dispatch (this is where polymorphism comes in handy). In other words, instead of `if x.class == String x.process_string else x.process_non_string`, you should simply have `x.process`, and then define `process` differently for `String` and other classes. Cleaner, less code, doesn't force the caller to know the class of the called object.