# Read XML commented value in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have XML with additional data in comments at the start of the XML file.
I want to read these details for some logging.

Is there any way to read XML commented values in Ruby?

The commented details are:

```
<!--  sessionId="QQQQQQQQ"  --><!-- ProgramId ="EP445522"  -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
require 'rexml/document'
require 'rexml/xpath'

File::open('q.xml') do |fd|
  xml = REXML::Document::new(fd)
  REXML::XPath::each(xml.root, '//comment()') do |comment|
    case comment.string
    when /sessionId/
      puts comment.string
    when /ProgramId/
      puts comment.string
    end
  end
end
```

Effectively what this does is loop through all comment nodes, then look for the strings you're interested in, such as `sessionId`. Once you've found the nodes you're looking for, you can process them using Ruby to extract the information you need.

Comment: `case comment.string ; when /sessionId/ then ... ; ...`

Comment: Hunh, didn't know you could do that. I'll edit it appropriately. Sometimes I think Ruby should have been called Sugar.

Comment: Welcome. Triple-equal magic in Ruby is actually a powerful tool. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5617086/2035262

Comment: _Ad hoc_ polymorphism at its finest.

Comment: Exactly. Plus an excellent idea of using it in `case` operator.

Answer (score 3):

Extracting values using Nokogiri and XPath:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML('<!--  sessionId="QQQQQQQQ"  --><!-- ProgramId ="EP445522"  -->')
comments = doc.xpath('//comment()')

tags = Hash[*comments.map { |c| c.content.match(/(\S+)\s*="(\w+)"/).captures }.flatten]
puts tags.inspect
# => {"sessionId"=>"QQQQQQQQ", "ProgramId"=>"EP445522"}
```